# Using Powershell to search for files and copy them using a text file

Tags: powershell

I'm struggling with trying to solve this at the moment as I'm new to Powershell. I have the below challenge to copy a few files from a number of sub-directories.
This is what I'm hoping to achieve with my script;

1. specify a directory to be searched  `$source`
2. specify the location of a file that contains a list of files  `$file_source`
3. specify destination

Processing:

search (1) including sub-directories for the files listed in (2) if exist copy them to (3)

This is all I have been able to come up with, but it doesn't work and I'm struggling on where to go from here. Thanks for looking.

```
$source= 'C:\Release\Database\' << has quite a few sub directories  but I want to search from there.
$file_source = 'C:\Release\SQL_Scripts.txt'
$target = 'C:\Release\Database1\'
get-content $file_source| ForEach-Object{ (Get-ChildItem -path $source -Recurse -Filter $_.fullname)  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

continue from where you are

```
$destination = "c:\destination"
$files = get-content $file_source

ForEach-Object ($f in $files) { 
$found = $null
$found = Get-ChildItem -path $source -Recurse | ? {$_.name -eq $f} 
if ($found -ne $null) {copy $found $destination}

}
```

i haven't thought much on how to handle duplicate name but that is something you need to work out

Comment: Thank you my final solution looked something like this >>
$source = Read-Host -Prompt 'enter path to database you want to package '
$file_source = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter path to list of files you want to package '
$target = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter path to where you want the files saved '
get-content $file_source | ForEach-Object { get-childitem -Path $source -Recurse -Filter "$_" } | Copy-Item -Destination $target